# Amazon-s3: An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the PutObject operation. Specifying both Canned ACLs and Header Grants is not allowed`

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3

I try to copy files from Jenkins server to the s3 server, but have the error `An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the PutObject operation`.

There are aws options:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::hhhh-backups/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The command with with I try to copy:

```
aws s3 cp allure-report/ s3://hhhh-backups --grants  read=uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers --recursive
```

- screenshot:
  [image]

---

I also added flag `acl bucket-owner-full-controller` and have other error:

> `An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the PutObject operation: Specifying both Canned ACLs and Header Grants is not allowed`

[image]

How to resolve it? **In general, I need to copy reports to the** `s3` **from Jenkins**. I can't do this with UI, I can't execute this with code (since I haven't AccessKey) and finally I can't execute this with a script from `aws cli`.
Also, I can't manage the `aws` options independently, but I can ask another to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try adding the `acl` flag and set it to `bucket-owner-full-control`.

your modified command will look like :

```
aws s3 cp allure-report/ s3://hhhh-backups --acl bucket-owner-full-control --recursive
```

for your reference :

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I updated the command and now  I have a new error. I modified the question, can you analyze it?

Comment: could you try to remove `--grant` flag and its value read= ... and try again with just `--acl` flag